# Node.js - AngularJS - MongoDB for community website

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean.io

I am wondering how well the MEAN stack (MongoDB, Express, Angular, Node) would fit to build a community websites, intra and/or extranet

I know I can use things like Drupal, Liferay and so on but I am just trying to understand the proper use case for the MEAN stack.

Suppose that I have to build a new community website or portal from the ground up. 
Would the MEAN stack be a good fit or is the LAMP stack still better in such a use case?

I am looking to learn the MEAN stack and I had to idea to build a "fake" community website which has lots of features, ideal to learn a technology stack like that, however if the technology is not ideal for such a purpose than I have to look into something else.

Comment: MEAN stack is perfect and complete solution for any web project. It even gives you some more advantages like websockets. IMHO its perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why to use the MEAN stack:

- One language for server, client, application model
- Nodejs concurrent connections handling (permanent connection client-server)
- Nodejs fits perfectly real-time applications
- Nodejs performances take advantage from the Google V8 Engine
- Nodejs asynchronous IO management guarantees more concurrent connections than other Web Server technologies (ex. Apache)
- Horizontal scalability (more trafic => more nodes, mongodb sharding)

Where not to use nodejs:

- High CPU usage operations because it's one threaded nature

Comment: Thanks. So to answer by own question based upon your answer. The MEAN stack would fit a community portal because it's not high in CPU. Business logic can remain in the Angular modules (client side)  and it can handle lots of connections. 
Am I correct?

Comment: Yes but don't forget scalability, performances, the fact that you'll use only one language.

Comment: A concern that I have with this stack is security. It seems that with Angular you have a lot of business logic running on the client, which to me, seems a bit risky. How secure is this? I mean, people could easily run their own JS code in the browser console to mess with my stuff. How big a risk is that?

Comment: There are tools developed to hide javascript code Client Side, google to find out the right for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have realised that learning JavaScript is a helpful before learning the MEAN stack and you need to be well at home with JavaScript.  You proposed project is one that requires a good grasp of both client-side JavaScript and server-side JavaScript.  Learning an effective way to control the quirks of JavaScript will also help.  Know JavaScript before learning MEAN and you should be fine.

Comment: JS is not an issue. I have been developing web applications for over 10 years. Mostly in java and PHP so because of that I already used a lot of JS. I'm not starting from scratch.

Comment: great. One of the features I mean is object oriented JavaScript and the techniques for implementing design patterns in JavaScript. You'll see all these a lot in the MEAN stack and they are not usually obvious if one has been writing only c/s JavaScript from other technologies - Java, PHP etc.  One great way to learn the MEAN stack is really to drop all baggages from other technologies and learn the MEAN stack from scratch.